# Visual Studio 2012 generate different set of dlls in bin forder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I don't understand why VS2012 generate different set of dlls for the same project on different machines.
What is the rule?

On my machine I have additionally 4 DLLs in bin folder:

```
Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll
Microsoft.Data.OData.dll
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
System.Spatial.dll
```

Project TargetFrameworkVersion v4.0

Project references:

```
AjaxControlToolkit
AjaxMin
mscorlib
System
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
System.Data
System.Data.Linq
System.Drawing
System.Core
System.Web.Extensions
System.Xml.Linq
System.Web.ApplicationServices
System.Web
System.Xml
System.Configuration
Telerik.Web.UI
```

So it may happen that published web app on one machine wont work on other machine due to dlls lack. What is the point?

UPD:
I looked into MSBuild logs. These 4 dlls are dependencies of AjaxControlToolkit. They were found on my machine and copied to bin folder during build process. Also I see in logs that many others dlls that were not found and not copied to bin. So it is strange behavior.

Comment: do you have different versions of entity framework installed?

Comment: @DanielA.White Can be. But I thought if .Net Framework version set for the project published app should work on any environment with this version installed.

Comment: Enable MSBuild logging and it willbd obvious which targets copied the dlls and from where. Then you know why.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you. Though it generated 228 pages of logs I've found these lines related with dll dependencies.